# Getting 2 values from the same column to display in the same result

Tags: sql

My table looks like this

```
PlayerID    PlayerName    Score
1           koates        0
2           tberckley      0
3           testAcc       3
```

I want to get the player names: koates and testAcc to display as the result but what I am writing displays the two results but in seperate results.

```
SELECT * FROM Players WHERE PlayerName='koates'
SELECT * FROM Players WHERE PlayerName='testAcc'
```

I am making a simple login page for a game and it will look for the username that the person enters

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for `IN` to combine the two:

```
select *
from Players
where PlayerName in ('koates', 'testAcc');
```

Comment: That worked, thanks, i know it was a simple question but i am new to SQL

Answer (score 0):

Sample Query:

```
select Result from
(
    select 'PlayerName' as Result from [Yourtablename]
    union
    select 'Score' as Result from [Yourtablename]
)tt 
   where Result is not null;
```